# Delphi XE6 crashes while installing bpl

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6, bpl

I have a project developed in delphi, that intends to install some components. These components are nothing but just inherited children of Firedac, and some other.

When I open the project in Delphi XE6, it opens fine. But, when I try to install the .bpl project by right clicking on project and selecting install option, the IDE crashes everytime.

The target platform is 32 bit.
Each time, when XE6 crashes and gets shut down, there is a error in event log. The screenshots for event logs are attached.[image: General Tab][image: Details Tab]

Also, I have tried with allowing the bds.exe app in firewall profiles.

It used to crash earlier also, but after trying for some time, it used to work. Now it does not. I have also tried with old code base for .bpl project but that does not help.

Any help on this is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The likely explanation is that there is a defect in the initialization or registration code of the bpl. The error code `0xC0000005` is the `NTSTATUS` code for an access violation.

Whilst the error is raised from the Delphi runtime module `rtl200.bpl` it is your package that is the likely culprit. Probably it has called the runtime library passing invalid data.

You will need to debug your package to solve this. Start by stripping code out of it progressively until the error disappears at that point you know that the error is caused by the code you just removed. Refine the process until you have a strong lead, and then follow that lead.